# Powershell Script Hard drive Inventory

Tags: windows, scripting, powershell

I've created a script to get hard drive information from our servers. The script use WMI to query the Win32_LogicalDisk class and returns "Size (GB)", "Free Space (GB)" and "Free Space (%)" for each device ID (local disk) of each server.

I want to sort by "Free Space (%)" for every device ID on each server. When I sort by "Free Space (%)", it does not show every device ID. One server has both C: and D: drives, but only the D: drive is shown in the output. If I remove the `Sort-Object "Free Space (%)"` it will show all device IDs for each server.

Can anyone help me with this script?

```
$computers   = C:\users\mtrajano\documents\powershell\scripts\list.txt
$logicalDisk = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType=3" -Computer $computers |
    Select-Object SystemName, DeviceID,
        @{ Name = "Size (GB)";       Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ($_.size / 1GB) } },
        @{ Name = "Free Space (GB)"; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ($_.freespace / 1GB) } },
        @{ Name = "Free Space (%)";  Expression = { "{0:P2}" -f (($_.freespace / 1GB) / ($_.size / 1GB)) } } |
            Sort-Object "Free Space (%)" |
                ConvertTo-Html |
                    Out-String

$messageParameters = @{
    To          = ""
    From        = ""
    Subject     = ""
    Body        = $logicalDisk
    SmtpServer  = ""
}

Send-MailMessage @messageParameters -BodyasHtml
```

Comment: Im new to the here.  I will see how I can format it better so that I can get help thanks.

Comment: Thanks Jscott for reformatting the look of my script. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I've ran this against all our capable Windows servers. I'm getting the same counts (using `Measure-Object`) whether I `Sort-Object "Free Space (%)"` or not. Could you provide some example output of the issue? Is it possible a machine was temporarily inaccessible via WMI between the two runs of this script?

Comment: sure I can provide some output examples of the issue.  Not sure how to attach a picture

Comment: Im not sure how to attach a picture here to show you Jscott

Comment: http://serverfault.com/editing-help#images